# Is it possible to embed section titles within subsections?

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec

I would like to to do the following

```
\section{Animals}
\subsection{Mammals}
\subsection{Birds}
```

and have it result in

1   Animals

1.2   Animals>**Mammals**

1.3   Animals>**Birds**

I have tried to do this with the `titlesec` package, but it does not seem to support embedded section commands. Could anyone shed light on this?

---

**Update**:
I would like to expand on this question. Let us assume that I have enabled subsubsubsection and subsubsubsubsection taken from [here](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.co.at/2010/06/how-to-activate-subsubsubsection-in.html). *See the following*:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\section{} % level 1
\subsection{} % level 2
\subsubsection{} % level 3
\paragraph{} % level 4 - equivalent to subsubsubsection
\subparagraph{} % level 5
```

The code *above* adds further embedded section support. The code *below* shows what I wish to achieve:

```
\section{Animals}
\subsection{Mammals}
\subsubsection{Nouns}
\paragraph{Related)
\subparagraph{Miscellaneous}
\subsection{Birds}
```

and have it result in

1   Animals

1.2   Animals>**Mammals**

1.2.1   Animals>Mammals>**Nouns**

1.2.1.1   Animals>Mammals>Nouns>**Related**

1.2.1.1.1    Animals>Mammals>Nouns>Related>**Miscellaneous**

1.3   Animals>**Birds**

Now, if I want each sub section to show the full path, how do I do it? The following does not work.

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\gdef\currsection{#1}#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection}\ → #1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection}\ → #1}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection}\ → #1}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection}\ → #1}
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer (use a different macro for each level) and the corresponding formatting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `explicit` option one has easy access to the section tile, so it can be saved and then used in the subsections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}  

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\gdef\currsection{#1}#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection}\ -- #1}


\begin{document}

\section{Animals}
\subsection{Mammals}
\subsection{Birds}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same principle applies for other levels; definitions for the defaults in standard classes can be found in page 23 (Section **9.2.Standard Classes**) of the `titlesec` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}  

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\gdef\currsection{#1}#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\gdef\currsubsection{#1}{\normalfont\currsection} -- #1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection\ -- \currsubsection} -- #1}

\begin{document}

\section{Animals}
\subsection{Mammals}
\subsubsection{Nouns}
\subsection{Birds}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps a cummulative definition os better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\gdef\currsection{#1}#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\gdef\currsubsection{\currsection\ -- #1}{\normalfont\currsection} -- #1}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\gdef\currsubsubsection{\currsubsection\ -- #1}{\normalfont\currsubsection} -- #1}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{\gdef\currparagraph{\currsubsubsection\ -- #1}{\normalfont\currsubsubsection} -- #1}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{{\normalfont\currparagraph} -- #1}

\begin{document}

\section{Animals}
\subsection{Mammals}
\subsubsection{Nouns}
\paragraph{Related}
\subparagraph{Miscellaneous}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much good sir! I would like to point out for other users that I had to remove \setmainfont[Path=/Users/username/Library/Fonts/]{LinBiolinum_R.ttf} from my code to get the bold to work. I suppose I could set that up manually with `fontspec`.

Comment: It is great to have a pro backing me up as I write this thesis. As I feared, the code seems to hang up when I get to the \paragraph level. `\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{{\normalfont\currsection\ -- \currsubsection -- \currsubsubsection} -- #1}`
does not work

Comment: @macmadness86 saying simply "does not work" is useless. I've added another option to my answer. If this still produces problems with your document, please feel free to open a fresh new question with this new issue and please include there a minimal working example illustrating the problem.

Comment: If you'll note in the comment above, I included the code so that you could hone in on the problem. You apparently did provide a solution. Thank you for you attention to detail and quick fixes!

Comment: @macmadness86 I didn't mean to be rude. If that was the impression caused, I apologize. I only meant that when an error appears, usually we need to see the code you are using (a complete document, in the sense of a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html), and not just snippets) and the error message so we can quickly diagnose the problem and provide a fix. Code snippets are almost always insufficient.